# How to use libxml2 on windows?

Tags: windows, go, libxml2

I want use this lib in my project:
https://github.com/terminalstatic/go-xsd-validate
I try to use debug is vscode on Windows. Now i am getting this error:

```
Build Error: go build -o ...\service\__debug_bin.exe -gcflags all=-N -l .\main.go
# pkg-config --cflags  -- libxml-2.0
Package libxml-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libxml-2.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libxml-2.0' found
pkg-config: exit status 1 (exit status 2)
```

The link above has instructions for installing libxml2 for linux:

```
curl -L ftp://xmlsoft.org/libxml2/LATEST_LIBXML2 -o ./LIBXML2_LATEST.tar.gz
tar -xf ./LIBXML2_LATEST.tar.gz
cd ./libxml2*
./configure --prefix=/usr  --enable-static --with-threads --with-history
make
sudo make install
```

But it did not help me, I spent a lot of time and did not come to anything.
I will be grateful for help.